# Lua's bytecode specification

Tags: documentation, lua, bytecode

Can anyone tell me where to find Lua's bytecode specification? I've been searching for 15 minutes, and I can't find *anything*.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Maybe [A No-Frills Introduction to Lua 5.1 VM Instructions](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14039839166840129336) contains what you're looking for?

There is also a table of the Lua 5.0 instruction set (Figure 5) in:

> Ierusalimschy, R.; Figueiredo, L. H.; Celes, W. (2005), "The implementation of Lua 5.0", *J. of Universal Comp. Sci.* **11** (7): 1159-1176

You can find the full text with a search on Google Scholar and I believe it's on lua.org as well. This reference is used by the Lua page on Wikipedia, which is always a good place to look for such things. :-)

Comment: LuaForge was shutdown. So, your link is dead. Do you recall what project was involved? Perhaps it was migrated to github...

Comment: The link now points to a Google Scholar search for that article. It returns hits on a number of different domains (including a direct link to the file on luaforge).

Comment: There is also a reference for Lua 5.3 bytecode here: https://github.com/dibyendumajumdar/ravi/blob/master/readthedocs/lua_bytecode_reference.rst

Answer (score 56):

The official definition is in [lopcodes.h](http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lopcodes.h.html).

Comment: Funny how somebody quoting your book gets the check when you provide the _reference_. Oh well, +1 from me.

Comment: @Bahbar, you made my day with that comment :P

Answer (score 6):

The only *specifications* for Lua are the language, standard libraries, and the C API. The creators of Lua intentionally left the VM unspecified for a couple main reasons:

- Lua can be *fully* implemented with any underlying architecture (VM, interpreter, compiler, etc.)
- The official Lua distribution doesn't have to worry about maintaining VM compatibility between versions

This means, for example, that you generally shouldn't use the Lua VM as a target for a compiler. If you'd like to know how the official Lua distribution's VM works as an example for your own curiosity, see the other answers.

Comment: It is. Just like the _whole official Lua source code_.

Comment: @jv110 You misunderstand. The Lua source code is merely a reference implementation of Lua, it is not "The" Lua. The only *specification* for Lua is the language itself, and the C API. Anyone can implement that specification using whatever underlying mechanics they want: VM, interpreter, FPGA/ASIC (physical chip). The creators of Lua have purposefully left it unspecified in order to make the language maximally flexible.

Comment: You're missing the point. He clearly asked about the official bytecode, which is (by _far_) the most common implementation. It doesn't matter if other implementations use it or not.

Comment: That's how you understand the intent of the question. As worded, this is a perfectly valid answer, if you interpret it a different way. It explains *why* he's having trouble searching for a specification. There isn't any.

Comment: He asked where he can find it, not why he can't find it. That doesn't neither answer the question nor help him in any way.

Comment: The other answers were already here and I referred to them at the end of mine. I didn't see any reason to say the same things as everyone else and just wanted to add some extra info to the conversation. I'm sorry that offends you.

Answer (score 5):

You can read [The Implementation of Lua 5.0](http://www.lua.org/doc/jucs05.pdf) online.

Comment: Very interesting read as I've always wanted to know how it all works in some code-related details.