# Documents about Lua 5.3 bytecode

Tags: lua, reverse-engineering

I'm attempting to write a Lua 5.3 VM in another language (this is for experimentations only).

The resources I've found for the moment are :

- [A No-Frills Introduction to Lua 5.1 VM Instructions](http://luaforge.net/docman/83/98/ANoFrillsIntroToLua51VMInstructions.pdf)
- [Lua 5.3 bytecode reference](http://the-ravi-programming-language.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lua_bytecode_reference.html)

As Lua breaks compatibility between each version, it's really difficult to find out how 5.3 bytecode works.

Do you have another source to share please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480678/luas-bytecode-specification.

Comment: At least [8 SO users](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/lua/topic-requests/4551) are wanting Lua bytecode reference manual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official definition of the instructions of the Lua VM is in [lopcodes.h](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lopcodes.h.html), starting at [OP_MOVE](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lopcodes.h.html#OP_MOVE).

Comment: See also [Lua 5.3 bytecode reference updated](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2016-12/msg00062.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's also the Lua 5.3 Bytecode Reference provided by the documentation for [the Ravi language](https://github.com/dibyendumajumdar/ravi/blob/master/README.rst)
(a language that uses a modified Lua 5.3 VM).

That can be found [here](https://github.com/dibyendumajumdar/ravi/blob/master/readthedocs/lua_bytecode_reference.rst)